# How to filter based on variable A if B is equal to zero, otherwise based on B?

Tags: swift, realm

My realm object is like the following

```
final class Item: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var editTime: Double = 0 // timestamp
    @objc dynamic var remindTime: Double = 0 // timestamp

}
```

I need to get data in a range, say between 2020-04-23 and 2020-04-24.
But the rule is comparing with `editTime` if `remindTime` is 0, otherwise use `remindTime` for comparison.
**The `sort` method in Swift `Sequence` is not a good choice in my case since it will load all data (might be several thousand items) to memory.**

Instead, I would like to use `NSPredicate`, but it seems not possible.

Currently, my solution is define another variable, say `filterTime`, to represent the `editTime` or `remindTime`.
The drawback is it requires to update the `filterTime` when update `remindTime` or `editTime` if `remindTime` is 0, which makes the code a little bit messy.

Is there any good solution to this?

Comment: You should make it clear that this data is stored in Realm, and that's why you can't just load it into memory (since several thousand items is relatively trivial, if it's only a matter of local storage/ram, and not networking)

Comment: Do you need to sort you results?

Comment: *But the rule*? Which rule is that? Can you clarify what you're asking? Are you stating that you want to filter by editTime if the remindTime property is 0? Also, can you explain what you mean by *the code a bit messy*? Maybe including an example of what you're attempted will help better explain what you're doing and what the coding issue is. Please take a moment and review  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)